# Displaying crystal report in a crystalReportViewer

Tags: .net

Please can anyone help me with this? I'm trying to Display crystal report in a crystalReportViewer and any time I try to run this code, it gives me

> "No source available: The call stacks contain only external code"

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet1
        Dim adpter As New DataSet1TableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter
        adpter.Fill(ds.Students)
        Dim report As New CrystalReport2
        report.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
```

Answer (score 0):

Your report has been built using a schema from your dataset? Check http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/09/Feeding-Crystal-Reports-from-your-application.aspx